# Parsec don't goto left even parse fail

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am  learning parsec with the example  https://github.com/JakeWheat/intro_to_parsing

As the code blow,  the result is always "right"

Anyone kindly give me some tips?

```
*Main> regularParse  parser4search "a"  
Loading package array-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.  
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.2 ... linking ... done.  
Loading package bytestring-0.10.4.0 ... linking ... done.  
Loading package text-1.1.0.0 ... linking ... done.  
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.  
Loading package mtl-2.1.3.1 ... linking ... done.  
Loading package parsec-3.1.7 ... linking ... done.  
Right (Num *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse  
*Main> regularParse  parser4search "1"  
Right (Num 1)
```

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

```
import Text.Parsec (parse,anyChar)
import Text.Parsec.String --(Parser)
import Text.Parsec.Char (oneOf, char, digit, satisfy,letter)
import Text.Parsec.Combinator (many1, choice, chainl1)
import Control.Applicative ((<|>), many)
import Control.Monad --(void)
import Data.Char --(isLetter, isDigit)


data SimpleExpr = Num Integer
             | Var String
             | Add SimpleExpr SimpleExpr
             | Parens SimpleExpr
             | Str [Char]
               deriving (Eq,Show)

regularParse p = parse p ""

parser4search:: Parser SimpleExpr
parser4search = do
    searchStr <- many digit
    return (Num (read searchStr))
```

Answer (score 3):

`many` means parse zero or more items.

`many1` means parse one or more items.

So, `many digit` succeeds with input "1", "24", or "".

`many1` succeeds with input "1", "24", but fails with "".  It sounds like this is what you want.

You also might want to look at `eof` so that trailing unparsed stuff will not be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The parsec does not give error (left value) because there is no error in parsing "a".
the `many digit` statement returns an empty string in case it does not find any integer characters.
To make your code work you need to handle the empty string.
For eg.

```
parser4search:: Parser SimpleExpr
parser4search = do
    searchStr <- many digit
    if searchStr == [] 
    then return (Num 0) 
    else return (Num (read searchStr))
```